# Detecting if a UDP port is open with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, udp, datagram

I am trying to check if a UDP port is open or not using Nodejs' dgram module.

Checking TCP is very easy, yet, as UDP is one way.

So, I think I can only check UDP ports that respond to requests.

If so, I guess I have to:

- send a request
- create a UDP server
- listen to any responses

Anyone has success in checking if a UDP port is open or not?

Any code samples to send a UDP request and expect the response by listening a specific port?

Thanks so much.

Comment: If by "open" you mean "allowed through firewall" and you have the ability to run commands on both the source and destination machine, the `nc` unix netcat utility can handle it. Server (destination) `nc -u -l 0.0.0.0 6666`, client `echo foo | nc -u ip.of.the.server 6666`

Comment: You have to create the server, or rather a receiving socket, *before* you send a request.

Comment: I don't have the ability to run commands in the destination server and, by "open", it seems like I need to check if the UDP port returns a response.

@EJP, do you have any code samples for that?

Comment: The way to test whether a UDP server is there is to *send* a request and *see* whether you get a response. You don't need a code sample for that.